# Insert data in model using loop

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

model.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Question(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Tag_name = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to enter more than 10000 data in Question model so i am using loop for this, but it did not work, how can i enter data using loop in Question Model.

I tried:

```
for i in range(1,3):
    p = Question(name='a'+str(i),Tag_name = 2) #id of tag and
    p.save()
```

Error:

```
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "filename", line 480, in __init__
  _setattr(self, prop, kwargs[prop])
  File "filename", line 537, in __set__
% self._get_set_deprecation_msg_params(),
  TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a 
  many-to-many set is  prohibited. 
  Use Tag_name.set() instead.
```

I know i am doing wrong.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Any error? Shoudn't it be `for i in range(1,1001)` here?

Comment: I have added the error here @neverwalkaloner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) method to add object to many-to-many relations. Something like this:

```
tag = Tag.objects.get(pk=2)
for i in range(1,3):
    p = Question(name='a'+str(i),Tag_name = 2) #id of tag and
    p.save()
    p. Tag_name.add(tag)
```

Or using [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

```
tag = Tag.objects.get(pk=2)
for i in range(1,3):
    p = tag.question_set.create(name='a'+str(i))
```

Note you should use snake case for class attributes name. So better to rename `Tag_name` to just `tags` for example:

```
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
tag = Tag.object.get(id=2)
for i in range(1,3):
    p = Question(name='a'+str(i)))
    p.save()
    p.Tag_name.add(tag)
```